# Random colors on polymer paper-cards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm just starting with Polymer (with a Rails backend) and I was wondering, can I apply a style on a polymer element, like normal html ?

My goal is to make a loop and have each card with a different header background-color.

I know I could define my different custom-styles and make an array of my classes to pick one during the loop, but I just want to know if there is a way to do something with less code like :

```
colors = ['red','blue','green']

<paper-card heading="<%= foo.name %>" elevation="3" style="--paper-card-header-color:<%= colors.sample %>">
```

Maybe it's too old-fashion.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

That code works?

If so, the same with less code would be:

```
<paper-card heading="<%= foo.name %>" elevation="3" style="--paper-card-header-color:<%= %w(red blue green).sample %>">
```

But why do you want less code? A "better" (some might say) goal is to have more readable code, in that case I think a helper would be a better choice:

```
<paper-card heading="<%= foo.name %>" elevation="3" style="--paper-card-header-color:<%= random_color %>">
```

And define a helper method `random_color`.

The code is not "old school" is up to you to do the "random" color pick in Ruby, or do it on JavaScript, I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: You were right to question the proposed code. It doesn't actually work.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer :-)
No my code doesn't work, that's why it's here on stackov.

Polymer doesn't allow to pass css inline apparently, but I was hoping someone has a way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your array of custom paper-card header colors, like this:

```
colors = ['red','blue','green']

<style is="custom-style">
  paper-card {
  }
  <% color in colors do %>
    .<%= color %> { --paper-card-header-color: <%= color %> }
  <% end %>
</style>
```

This will produce these custom color styles:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  <% color in colors do %>
    .red { --paper-card-header-color: <%= red %> }
    .blue { --paper-card-header-color: <%= blue %> }
    .green { --paper-card-header-color: <%= green %> }
  <% end %>
</style>
```

This will work for CSS named colors.  If you want to use the full range of CSS colors, you can detect the `#XXXXXX` format and name color styles appropriately:

```
colors = ['red','blue','green','#c0c0c0','B0306F']

<style is="custom-style">
  paper-card {
  }
  <% colors.each_with_index do |color,index| %>
    <% if color =~ /^#?[0-9a-f]$/i %>
      <% color = color.gsub(/\D+/, '').downcase %>
      <% colors[index] = color %>
      .color-<%= color %> { --paper-card-header-color: #<%= color %> }
    <% else %>
      .<%= color %> { --paper-card-header-color: <%= color %> }
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</style>
```

Note that in this example, the `colors` array is modified with the name of the color class.  A separate array of color class names could be kept, if desired.

You can apply these styles while processing the cards, by applying the appropriate color class:

```
<% cards.each do |card| %>
  <paper-card heading="<%= card.title %>" class="<%=colors.sample%>">
<% end %>
```

If you want to apply a random color each time through the loop, your approach of using `Array#sample` is very sensible and smart coding.  The `Array#sample` method will give you a pseudo-random color from the list; however, you may get repeated colors more frequently than you like, especially with small color lists.

For example, I ran this code:

```
colors = ['red','blue','green']
20.times { puts "#{colors.sample}" }
```

and I got this output:

```
green
green
green
blue
red
green
red
green
blue
green
red
red
blue
green
blue
red
red
green
red
blue
```

If you'd prefer to have unique colors, but in random order, you can use `Array#shuffle` to re-order the list of colors randomly:

```
random_colors = colors.shuffle

<% cards.each do |card| %>
  <paper-card heading="<%= card.title %>" class="<%= random_colors.shift %>">
<% end %>
```

If you have more cards to produce than colors, you might want to make `random_colors` be large enough to accommodate the entire run of cards:

```
random_colors = colors.shuffle.cycle((cards.length.to_f / colors.length.to_f).ceil).inject([]) {|array, color| array << color }

<% cards.each do |card| %>
  <paper-card heading="<%= card.title %>" class="<%= random_colors.shift %>">
<% end %>
```

In this case, if `cards` was a run of 7 cards, you would have a `random_colors` array of 9 colors, repeating the 3 random colors 3 times.

You can also reset the `random_colors` array inside the loop to make multiple randomly ordered runs:

```
colors = ['red','blue','green']
random_colors = []

<% cards.each do |card| %>
  random_colors = colors.shuffle if random_colors.length == 0
  <paper-card heading="<%= card.title %>" class="<%= random_colors.shift %>">
<% end %>
```

This will produce a new randomly ordered array each time `random_colors` is empty.  You definitely have options, and which is a better solution depends on your goals and what you feel works in your situation.

Comment: +1 for explaining how to generate random colors, but you can't assign `--paper-card-header-color` inline like that. That code was only hypothetical. The CSS variable must be assigned inside a `custom-style`, as shown in this [`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/bovixib/edit?html,output).

Comment: @tony19 Thanks for the feedback.  I actually thought the OP was asking about how to generate custom colors, so that's what I answered.  I actually didn't validate (obviously!) the polymer syntax.  I'm going to use your jsbin link (as well as some other intro polymer docs) to correct the polymer-oriented parts of my answer.  Again, thanks for taking the time to review and feedback!

Comment: No worries. I'm looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your detail answer !
As @tony19 said, Polymer as a specific way to modify css, but I was hoping someone know how to pass it inline.
Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @charly-m I don't know if you saw, but I had updated my answer.  It now shows how to customize `paper-card` colors, even a little more simply than your example for simple colors, and shows how to use RGB hex colors in the same way.  After that, it shows 3 additional methods to use random ordered color production.

Answer (score 0):

So, 
Apparently Polymer don't like inline css.

I've come to this, I

For the record, I tried to solve the problem and I came to this (ugly) solution : (I think we can do it in a better way using javascript.)

`colors_key = ['leonardo','donatello','mickelangelo','raphael','casey']`

`colors = {colors_key[0]=>'blue',colors_key[1]=>'purple',colors_key[2]=>'orange',colors_key[3]=>'red',colors_key[4]=>'green'}`

`<style is="custom-style">
    <% colors.each do |k,v| %>
      <%= ".#{k}" %> { --paper-card-header-color: <%= "#{v}" %> }
    <% end %>
  </style>`

`<paper-card heading="<%= foo.name %>" class="<%=colors_key.sample%>">`

Question close, but any improvement welcome !